# How to user Filter custom data in angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter the value remove decimal and add $ in angular controller .. please let me know if you have any idea

```
$scope.data = [{
        "key": " Logo",
        "color": "#004400",
        "values": [
            [0, parseInt($scope.myappslogo)]
        ]
    }, {
        "key": "Sell",
        "color": "#00cc00",
        "values": [
            [0, parseInt($scope.myapps.sell)]
        ].$filter('currency')
    }, {
        "key": "Total",
        "color": "#009900",
        "values": [
            [0, parseInt($scope.myapps.amount)] | currency
        ]
    }

];
```

Comment: what did you want to do ? can you add an example of the data before / after

Comment: inside value in need to use filtered value with $5000000 instead of 50000.00

Comment: Actually  i am using d3.js for graph ..

Answer (score 2):

The correct use of `$filter` is like this:

```
$filter('currency')($scope.myapps.amount);
```

you can also add optionals:

```
$filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)
```

So I guess you want this:

```
$filter('currency')($scope.myapps.amount, '$', 0);
```

[ngdocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Now if you have an array of values you can put the above in a function and map the array.
e.g:

```
function mapCurrency(n) {
    return $filter('currency')(n, '$', 0);
}

tranformedValues = $scope.data[0].values[0].map(mapCurrency);
```

Comment: but how can i use in my case .

Comment: you didn't mention at first that this was used for a graph. so this won't work for you,  you want a number and not a string I guess.   Just informational: replacing this `parseInt($scope.myappslogo)` with this `$filter('currency')($scope.myappslogo, '$', 0)` gives the frormat you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution ... inside d3 option i can use filter like this

```
$scope.options = {
          chart: {
            type: 'multiBarHorizontalChart',
            height: 150,
            x: function (d) {
              return d[0];
            },
            y: function (d) {
              return d[1];
            },
            stacked: true,
             xAxis: {
                    showMaxMin: true
                },
             yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Values',
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format('$')(d);
                    }
             }
          }
        };
```